# R- Calculating duration between time and date

Tags: r

I have a big data set that contains 1. the admission date (day, month, year, hour, minute all in separate columns) and time and 2. the departure date and time (combined in single column).

But the data is in a format that makes it difficult to calculate the duration of admission.

```
  day  month  year  hour  minute  departuredatetime2
1 6    10     2010  14    20      6/12/2010 17:20
2 26   10     2010  19    25      26/10/2010 21:25
3 10   12     2010  14    30      10/12/2010 17:00
4 14   4      2011  13    00      14/04/2011 16:45
5 20   1      2012  12    30      20/01/2012 15:30
6 20   2      2012  23    30      21/02/2012 03:30
.
.
1095
```

I'm hoping to achieve something like

```
   admissionduration(hours)
1  3.0
2  2.0
3  2.5
4  3.75
5  3.0
6  4.0
.
.
1095
```

I'm not too sure how to approach this in R, not sure how I can subtract the admission date and time from the departure date and time.

Thank you for your time

Comment: should month be 12 for first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using `tidyverse` functions :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::unite(d1, -departuredatetime2, sep = "-") %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = lubridate::dmy_hm), 
         diff_hour = as.numeric(difftime(departuredatetime2, d1, units = 'hour')))


#                   d1  departuredatetime2 diff_hour
#1 2010-12-06 14:20:00 2010-12-06 17:20:00      3.00
#2 2010-10-26 19:25:00 2010-10-26 21:25:00      2.00
#3 2010-12-10 14:30:00 2010-12-10 17:00:00      2.50
#4 2011-04-14 13:00:00 2011-04-14 16:45:00      3.75
#5 2012-01-20 12:30:00 2012-01-20 15:30:00      3.00
#6 2012-02-20 23:30:00 2012-02-21 03:30:00      4.00
```

---

In base R, you can do :

```
df$d1 <- do.call(paste, df[-6])
df$d1 <- as.POSIXct(df$d1, format = "%d %m %Y %H %M")
df$departuredatetime2 <- as.POSIXct(df$departuredatetime2, 
                            format = "%d/%m/%Y%H:%M")
df$diff_hour <- as.numeric(difftime(df$departuredatetime2, df$d1, units = 'hour'))
```

The logic in both the approaches remain the same, we combine all the columns except the last one to get a timestamp (`d1`) and subtract it with `departuredatetime2` to get the difference in hours.

Answer (score 0):

This regex approach should work:

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  hour = c("14","19","14","13"),
  min = c("20","25","30","00"),
  departure = c("6/12/2010 17:20", "26/10/2010 21:25", "10/12/2010 17:00", "14/04/2011 16:45")
)
```

First calculate admission times:

```
admissions <- as.numeric(hm(paste0(df$hour, ":", df$min)))
```

Then calculate departures times:

```
departures <- as.numeric(hm(sub(".*(\\d{2}:\\d{2})", "\\1", df$departure)))
```

Finally, calculate time difference in hours:

```
df$admissionduration <- (departures - admissions)/3600
```

Result:

```
df
  hour min        departure admissionduration
1   14  20  6/12/2010 17:20              3.00
2   19  25 26/10/2010 21:25              2.00
3   14  30 10/12/2010 17:00              2.50
4   13  00 14/04/2011 16:45              3.75
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution you can use several functions from [`lubridate`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) package for that.

- Convert several admission columns with [`make_datetime()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/make_datetime.html).
- Convert one departure column to Date and time object with [`dmy_hm()`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd_hms.html).
- Check the interval between departure and admission with [`%--%`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/interval.html) and get the result in hours by dividing that by one hour with [`dhours(1)`](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/duration.html).

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

# 1. merge and convert admission columns to one POSIXct date and time object
# 2. convert departure column to a POSIXct date and time object
# 3. count a difference between admission and departure and display that in hours
df %>%
  mutate(admission               = make_datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute),
         departure               = dmy_hm(departuredatetime2),
         admissionduration_hours = admission %--% departure / dhours(1))
#>   day month year hour minute departuredatetime2           admission
#> 1   6    10 2010   14     20    6/10/2010 17:20 2010-10-06 14:20:00
#> 2  26    10 2010   19     25   26/10/2010 21:25 2010-10-26 19:25:00
#> 3  10    12 2010   14     30   10/12/2010 17:00 2010-12-10 14:30:00
#> 4  14     4 2011   13      0   14/04/2011 16:45 2011-04-14 13:00:00
#> 5  20     1 2012   12     30   20/01/2012 15:30 2012-01-20 12:30:00
#> 6  20     2 2012   23     30   21/02/2012 03:30 2012-02-20 23:30:00
#>             departure admissionduration_hours
#> 1 2010-10-06 17:20:00                    3.00
#> 2 2010-10-26 21:25:00                    2.00
#> 3 2010-12-10 17:00:00                    2.50
#> 4 2011-04-14 16:45:00                    3.75
#> 5 2012-01-20 15:30:00                    3.00
#> 6 2012-02-21 03:30:00                    4.00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(day = c(6L, 26L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 20L), month = c(10L, 
10L, 12L, 4L, 1L, 2L), year = c(2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 
2012L), hour = c(14L, 19L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 23L), minute = c(20L, 
25L, 30L, 0L, 30L, 30L), departuredatetime2 = c("6/10/2010 17:20", 
"26/10/2010 21:25", "10/12/2010 17:00", "14/04/2011 16:45", "20/01/2012 15:30", 
"21/02/2012 03:30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```